# How to avoid creating different callback interface for each retrofit response

Tags: java, android, android-activity, retrofit, repository-pattern

I wanted to extract the retrofit request implementation from activity. So I thought of creating
a class which makes all the requests and send the result through an interface to the activity.

I created an interface for the response callback as below

```
public interface IApi {

    void onSuceessTodo(Todo todo);
    void onSuceessPosts(List<Post> postList);
    void onFailure(String errorMessage);
}
```

And I have created a repository class. It makes two different requests

```
public class Repository {

    public void getPosts (IApi iApi) {
        JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);
        Call<List<Post>> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getPosts();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    iApi.onFailure("Not successful");
                    return;
                }

                List<Post> posts = response.body();
                iApi.onSuceessPosts(posts);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Post>> call, Throwable t) {
                iApi.onFailure(t.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    public void getTodos (IApi iApi , int id) {
        JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);
        Call<Todo> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getTodo(id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Todo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Todo> call, Response<Todo> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    iApi.onFailure("Not successful");
                    return;
                }

                Todo todo = response.body();
                iApi.onSuceess(todo);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Todo> call, Throwable t) {
                iApi.onFailure(t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
 }
```

Now in the activity I'm implementing the callback interface. But for this activity I only need to get the `Todo` not the `Posts` so I override the needed functions and made the activity as abstract but I ran into issues when I ran the application

```
ava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
```

Which I think it because I can't make the activity abstract class and I don't want to create multiple interfaces for each request call because I will have many!

The activity

```
public abstract class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IApi{
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Repository repository = new Repository();
        repository.getTodos(this , 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuceessTodo(Todo todo) {
        Log.d("test" , "onSuceess");
    }


    @Override
    public void onFailure(String errorMessage) {
        Log.d("test" , "onFailure");

    }
}
```

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Create an abstract class **BaseActivity**, something like this:

```kotlin
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IApi
```

2. Create abstract methods in your **BaseActivity**

```kotlin
public abstract void onSuceessTodo(Todo todo) {
    Log.d("test" , "onSuceess");
}

public abstract void onFailure(String errorMessage) {
    Log.d("test" , "onFailure");

}

public abstract void onSuceessTodo(String errorMessage) {
    Log.d("test" , "onFailure");

}
```

3. Your **MainActivity** class should be something like that

```kotlin
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity
```

4. Override the methods you just need to override in your MainActivity class

Tell me if this working for you! (Sorry for my bad Java ✌️)

Comment: I believe this will work. But I don't feel it makes sense to place those functions on the baseActivity

Comment: If you put these methods in the BaseActivity you could define a standard behavior for all the Activities that inherits from this BaseActivity, or at least hast a basic implementation that you can override in every specific Activity that inherits from this BaseActivity. @Rahul